# Skoda octavia A8 2022 mk4 gives jerking while accelerating

Tags: skoda, octavia, mk4

My skoda octavia A8 2022 is giving a jerking while  accelerating.. Especially in sports mode.. In the mid RPMs.

https://youtu.be/uX0gSSRiWk4

What to do to solve it. Service center isn't saying anything

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the video supposed to be showing us? And if this is a 2022, shouldn't you take it to the dealership under warranty to get something fixed?

Comment: Also, is the car equipped with a CVT?